# PHP - Get contents from site with different port then 8080

Tags: php

I am trying to display text from a url onto another site.

I have used `file_get_contents` in combo with http://gimmes.net/celtcast/test.txt
Which worked! Yay!

But the thing is now, I tried changing it to `http://celtcast.gkstreamen.nl:8086/7.html`

Which has the values I need, but I ran into a issue, it didn't show what I wanted, well, it showed, nothing.

Which is also no good, I found out that the problem was laying with that the php

> couldn't access the other server cos it's not :8080.

I would like some help on how I could make this work; 
At the end I just need a variable of the text

which is something like '17,1,24,500,16,128,Triakel - Kom blicka in pa en kyrkogard'
And I will parse it after that...

Thanks!

Comment: hi @Gimmes, when I click on link provided by you, I get this `15,1,24,500,14,128,Beltaine - Rocky Road To Dublin - The Butterfly`.Is that what you want? or do you want something else?

Comment: I want to get that to my php, but my php doesn't seem to be able to access http://celtcast.gkstreamen.nl:8086/7.html cos of the port;

Comment: why dont you show your php code where you are trying to access the URL in question ?

Answer (score 1):

Use CURL :

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://celtcast.gkstreamen.nl/7.html'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8086); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 8086); 
$result = curl_exec($curl); // parse $result then
?>
```